# What is the average time of running line 4 of MINIMUM function?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

how much be run the line 4 of this function in average? O(logn) or O(n)

```
Minimum(A,n)
1. min= +inf
2. for i:1 to n
3.  do if min>A[i]
4.    then min=A[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is not sorted (otherwise see below):

It is O(n) because:

- You have to look at each entry of the array *at least once* otherwise an entry you did not look at might be even smaller
- You have to look at each entry *at most once* because you never forget what is the current minimum.
- An array is direct access (no seek time)

If the array is sorted then finding the minimum is just taking the first entry, that is O(1). But if you only need the minimum once (and not repeatedly getting-and-deleting the min) it is not worth sorting the array because sorting takes O(n*log(n))